# Unable to boot OS - No boot device found. Press any key to reboot machine

Tags: boot, 64-bit, microcode

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my laptop. Even though the installer ran without errors, I failed to boot. I tried it 8 times, both in Legacy and UEFI mode. Still nothing. It shows only: `No boot device found. Press any key to reboot machine`.

Update: I have identified the problem. Outdated microcode of my CPU was causing the problem. Reinstalled Windows and applied the update.
Previous version: `20090330`
Update version: `20180425`

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Did you install it on a fresh hard drive, did you make all the necessary partitions? What do you mean "failed to boot", what happens when you try to boot?

Comment: My laptop says "No boot device found. Press any key to reboot machine"

Comment: And no, it's not a fresh HDD and yes I created all necessary partitions

Comment: @MashrafeAiman Please [edit] the question to add details, including what you already mentioned, plus your laptop model, since the solution to this issue seems to be hardware/firmware specific.

Comment: Try using whatever bootable device you used to install the OS, and tell us what shows up. (You may want to edit your questions with these details)

Comment: @Mashrafe Aiman.. After Succeful installation when you restarted "no boot device found" at this point change your boot mode to opposite of what it is showing.. BIOS>UEFI & UEFI>BIOS

Comment: I did that 8 times

Comment: Making the same mistake eight times does not fix the mistake. See [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

Comment: Ok problem fixed.

Comment: Had to update microcode

Comment: @MashrafeAiman could you answer your question with details of how you fixed the problem?

Comment: Installed Windows 10 first

Comment: Then updated microcode

Comment: Then tried installing Ubuntu again

Comment: This time it succeeded
And now I'm able to boot

Comment: @MashrafeAiman Please post the steps that fixed your problem as an "answer" by clicking the "answer your question" button below. "Comments" is not the right place for answers and it's completely fine to answer your own question : )

Answer (score 0):

Outdated microcode of CPU was causing the problem. Reinstalled Windows and applied the update. Previous version: 20090330 Update version: 20180425.